# Fallback og:image if no images are present in an ext:news story

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

TYPO3 v 7.16.
cs_seo 2.3.3
news 6.3.0

I have disabled cs_seo on my news detail page and ext:news is generating the correct og & twitter card meta data as expected. However, if I have a story that doesn't feature an image, no default image is present. Is it possible to set a fallback/default image to be used for News stories?

(If I enable cs_seo on the news detail page, it overrides any metadata generated by ext:news)

Thanks again,

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bernd - thanks for getting back to me. The "dummy image" is set, however it is not configured to be included on Detail pages (as far as I can tell).

I came across a support thread for cs_seo extension which allows you to set a fallback image.

https://github.com/clickstorm/cs_seo/issues/92

I used the following typoscript setup on my Detail page.

```
tx_csseo {
1 = tx_news_domain_model_news
1.fallback {
    og_image = fal_media
}
}
```

In the cs_seo extension I had to set the TSConfig PID to my Detail page, I also included the Page TSConfig "Extend News Records".

I then noticed that on News Detail pages I had two sets of OG metadata. One being generated by ext:News and the other by cs_seo. I removed the following partial include from my Detail Template

```
<f:render partial="Detail/Opengraph" arguments="{newsItem: newsItem, settings:settings}" />
```

I now have one set of OG tags and a fallback image in place.

Answer (score 2):

The default templates of ext:news include the usage of a default image. You configure it in the TS constants.

You might have 'cleaned' the templates when you modified it to your version.